# I want Retrieve firebase analytics (events data) through rest api using python

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I did some research and found that it possible to retrieve firebase analytics data (events etc. ) using Google Bigquery. However,  there is a cost attached to Biquery. Is there any REST API to extract firebase analytics data?